todo-comments.nvim: :TodoTelescope is searching for Todo comments in all of my files, not just the ones in the tree
I'm having some trouble using folke/todo-comments.nvim. The highlighting works great and all, but when I use <leader>st (my shortcut for :TodoTelescope), it is searching through all the files I have in any directory. This does happen with other functions like :TodoTrouble as well.
This is the plugins.lua return for folke/todo-comments.nvim:
{
  "folke/todo-comments.nvim",
  cmd = { "TodoTrouble", "TodoTelescope" },
  event = "LazyFile",
  dependencies = { "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim" },
  config= function()
    local todo_comments = require("todo-comments")

    todo_comments.setup()
    end,
  keys = {
    { "]t", function() require("todo-comments").jump_next() end, desc = "Next Todo Comment" },
    { "[t", function() require("todo-comments").jump_prev() end, desc = "Previous Todo Comment" },
    { "<leader>xt", "<cmd>TodoTrouble<cr>", desc = "Todo (Trouble)" },
    { "<leader>xT", "<cmd>TodoTrouble keywords=TODO,FIX,FIXME<cr>", desc = "Todo/Fix/Fixme (Trouble)" },
    { "<leader>st", "<cmd>TodoTelescope<cr>", desc = "Todo" },
    { "<leader>sT", "<cmd>TodoTelescope keywords=TODO,FIX,FIXME<cr>", desc = "Todo/Fix/Fixme" },
  },
},

I've already installed ripgrep and fzf, and I have all the dependencies of the project installed. I'm also using LazyVim as my Neovim distribution and Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS as my OS.

For those with the same problem, I've found out that neo-tree does not cd to the current directory. To correct that, you need to add this to your init.lua file:
vim.cmd([[ autocmd BufEnter * silent! lcd %:p:h ]])
